# Action Bar doesn't change back

Tags: android

Previously I had changed the android:minSdkVersion to "1", so I lost the Action Bar and just a bar with the app title shows, and now that Ive changed it to "8", the Action Bar is not being shown. Instead it stil shows just the title bar :(
How to get back the action bar?

Help.

Comment: Did you clean the build before you compiled the second time?

Comment: Yes I cleaned. Does any other setting changed when I changed it to "1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As elimirks stated out one possibility is to clean your project before compiling it again.

**Much more likely should still be the following:**
SDK-version 8 represents Android 2.2 whereas the `ActionBar` was introduced with Android 3.0 (SDK-version 11), so 8 is not even enough to ensure that. Set it up to 11 and see what happens.

Regardless, to ensure targeting a specific platform or feature (as the `ActionBar` is) you should use `android:targetSDKVersion`. This attribute specifies the SDK that your code will be compiled against.

For further reading on that topic:[uses-sdk](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Comment: Nope. I had just changed it to "1", now changing back to "8" doesn't revert the changes :(

Comment: Do you have the `targetSDKVersion`-attribute set? If not it's clear why it is not working with "8". See my answer for an explanation of that behaviour! And maybe you can read more on the topic with the link I edited.